# подача предложений на аукционе в последнюю секунду

Tags: php

Всем привет. есть некий аукцион, идет отсчет времени(10 минут). при подаче нового предложения счетчик должен начинаться заного. есть такая проблема - если попасть с предложением в последнюю секунду, то предложение принимается, а аукцион заканчивается. Может кто нибудь сталкивался с такой задачей? Как можно обойти это место?

Comment: Код покажите, явно проблемы в коде раз у вас такая проблема.

Comment: Если данные аукциона хранятся в БД, то думаю наиболее правильным было бы сделать триггер в БД, который при добавлении ставки ставит дату окончания на текущий момент + 10 минут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не глядя в код, можно предположить, что взаимодействие с БД забыли завернуть в транзакцию или уровень изоляции транзакций ниже SERIALIZABLE. За время работы функции закрытия аукциона данные, которые она прочла в начала, успели устареть, но ей (**ошибочно!**) удается успешно закоммитить свою транзакцию, это и ломает логику аукциона. Если сами транзакции расставлены верно, то при уровне изоляции SERIALIZABLE попытка закоммитить такую транзакцию должна выбросить ошибку/исключение. Функция закрытия аукциона должна корректно обрабатывать эти ошибки и в цикле повторять попытки отработать всю логику внутри новой транзакции.

Comment: Все правильно вы говорите. У меня в коде не был реализован механизм возврата аукциона в активную часть. Т.е. был демон, который завершал аукцион по времени, заявка принималась, аукцион как бы продлялся, но уже стоял флаг что он завершен.